# Ignoring Application Default Credentials {0}: using explicit setting for API key instead

Tags: java, android, api, debugging

I was trying to make an android app that reads data from a txt file and translate it into required language. It is running but after clicking the translate button it is taking long time to set the API key explicitly giving the message

`Ignoring Application Default Credentials {0}: using explicit setting for API key instead.`

The reason might be that I am using the line

`Translate  translate = TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setApiKey("***********************").build().getService();`

where ************************* is the Api key and setApiKey is showing depreciated.

2 questions:

a.any alternative of setApiKey

b.how to set API key explicitly as shown by error

Please answer specificly.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled the google cloud traslation api once more and now the problem is not showing any more.